# How can I get the var of a multimethod?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use [dire](https://github.com/MichaelDrogalis/dire) to add hooks to multimethods. The author says it might not work.
Here is an example with a normal function:

```lisp
(ns mydire.prehook
  (:require [dire.core :refer [with-pre-hook!]]))

(defn times [a b]
  (* a b))

(with-pre-hook! #'times
  "An optional docstring."
  (fn [a b] (println "Logging something interesting.")))

(times 21 2) ; => "Logging something interesting."
```

As you can see, `with-pre-hook!` is passed `(var times)` (which is the same as `#'times`).

The problem is that when calling `var` for a multimethod I'm getting an exception:
`clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol`

**Is there a way to make this work?**

Below is my code sample:

```lisp
(defmulti get-url identity)

(defmethod get-url :stackoverflow
  [site]
  "http://stackoverflow.com")

(with-pre-hook! (var (get-method get-url :stackoverflow))
  (fn [x] (println "getting url for stackoverflow.")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` is a macro, it does not evaluate its argument. If you give it a list, it will not evaluate the list, it will reject it, because it's a list and not a symbol.

There is no var to attach to with a specific method, because `defmethod` does not create a var, it modifies the dispatch of the multimethod it is attached to. The value returned by `get-method` is a function, not a var.

Having looked at `dire`, it specifically needs a var to act on, and won't work on a specific method of a multimethod without some amount of redesign. So no, you can't use `with-pre-hook` on a specific method, though it might work on a multimethod itself (including all of its methods).

Comment: Are you saying that there is nothing I can pass to `with-pre-hook` so that I can hook to a multimethod? Sorry if your conclusion is obvious, but my limited knowledge of clojure makes your 2nd paragraph difficult for me to fully understand.

Comment: if `with-pre-hook` needs a var, there is no way to give it a particular multimethod implementation, because there is no var that goes with it. The multimethod itself (in your case `#'get-url`) is a var, but wrapping that would wrap every method of `get-url`, not just the specific one you wanted to wrap.

Comment: @FranciscoDibar I looked at the `dire` lib and have updated with a more explicit answer, hope that helps.